# DHTMLX Spreadsheet - global is undefined (vite + vue 2)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vite, dhtmlx

I Installed [dhx-spreadsheet@3.0.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dhx-spreadsheet) in a Vue + Vite Project.

But It Gives an Error That:
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setImmediate')`

[image: DHTMLX Spreadsheet - global is undefined (vite + vue 2)]

[image: DHTMLX Spreadsheet - global is undefined (vite + vue 2)]

I Try a  Vue + Webpack Project with This Libray and Everything Is Fine.

Also tried:
 `define: { global: 'globalThis' }`
in Vite Config File and it Doesn't Affect.

The Webpack Project: https://github.com/DHTMLX/vuejs-widgets

I Think This Package Has Issues With Bite, Is There Anyway to Fix This in Vite?

Answer (score 0):

You can check solution there
https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/602

It seems that next in the vite.config.js must solve the issue

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
})
```

if somehow it doesn't work, you can try to add the next code before including the spreadhsheet's js file

```html
<script>
if (typeof (window as any).global === 'undefined') {
  (window as any).global = window;
}
</script>
<script src="spreadsheet.js"></script>
```